# jQuery dont see click on appened object

Tags: jquery, append

I have a code like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".add").bind ('click',
        function ()
        {
            $('.main').append('<div class="add">Add element 2</div>');
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="main"><div class="add">Add element</div></div>
```

When virtual objects ".add" are appended to ".main", jquery does not react for click on them

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/on/ / "Direct and delegated events
"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because you bound the action to only existing *.add* elements before you created the new ones.

You need to bind the click to the *.main* element with a specific selector provided as the second parameter in the *on* function.

```
$('.main').on('click', '.add', function (){
    $('.main').append('<div class="add">Add element 2</div>');
});
```

It's pretty intuitive really. With your code, you're saying *find all add elements on the page and bind this function to each one*. The ones added later therefore won't have this function bound.

With the correct code, you're saying *find the main element and bind a function to it, but only execute the function when a child element with the class .add is clicked*.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.bind()`, but instead use `.on()` or, if you have a pre 1.7 version of jQuery, `.delegate()`.

Binding is a one-time action, it doesn't listen to new items in the DOM.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated. If you're going to suggest the delegate flavor of `.on()`, it'd be better to suggest `.delegate()` for jQuery 1.6 below instead.

Comment: Thx for the correction @RichardNeilIlagan, when I wrote it I already felt dirty mentioning .live()

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect changes mentioned in comments, and corrected the version prior to which you can't use `.on()`.